# How to pick start and end date in bootstrap in single input text field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

```
$('#pwd').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '+1d',
    endDate: '+7d',
});
```

This the script file.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Date" >
```

This is the input field.I want to fetch the start and end date in a single text field.Any help is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard I would recommend the daterange picker to easily pick start and end date. But as you want it in a single text field you could use the option `multidate`

Datepicker config:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    //..
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '+1d',
    endDate: '+7d',
    multidate: 2 //Just allow 2 dates to be picked start and enddate
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vh1oknf7/86/

EDIT:

This is some example code to "fix" your extra comment. You can use the `changeDate`event for that. This javascript solution isn't perfect but should get you going! Tweak it to your needs!

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vh1oknf7/88/

Comment: Thanks. The start date is restricted to current day. I want it to be dynamic but the end has to 7th day.Could you help me with also.

Comment: I've added an extra example to show how to possibly fix you extra question!

Comment: Thanks but this is not what is was asking,let's just say if i select any date on calendar any month , it should pick end date as 7th day automatically.Could you help me with this.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle example, this works on empty field but should be tweaked to fix all cases. But it should get you going!

Comment: For other months the date changes but the month remains the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91589/discussion-between-abhishek-singh-and-acrobat).